# DC braking on induction motor (as done by VFD)

Tags: motor, vfd, braking

I know the principle of DC braking on an induction motor; a fixed magnetic field is induced in the stator and it makes the field in the rotor align to it.

However due to the working of the induction motor the is no field when the rotor is stopped or at synchronous speed (no slip gives no counter EMF); still some VFD manufacturers says that DC braking can hold the load. This doesn't make sense for me (for *asynchronous* motors, of course). Other manufacturer use a very low frequency (like 0.2Hz) to keep torqued the motor without spinning at that makes sense to me.

So, what's the truth? Can a DC braked asynchronous motor hold the load (with huge heating, of course) or a rotating field is needed to do it?

Comment: Do you just need to hold it steady in one position or break a spinning one? For the former, would just shorting all phases together give you enough holding torque?

Comment: DC injection is more-or-less like a short but I don't get how could be an asynch rotor (i.e. a squirrel cage) be influenced by a DC field if it's already stopped